# print out from if else statement containing an id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have made this function. I am working with Razor and C#. If an order has a SupplierId of one of the numbers below, I have to print out the text that belongsto the SupplierId:

```
@{
    var pointShop = Model.Order.OrderLines[0];
    string supplier == null;

    if (pointShop.SupplierId = 27942) {
    supplier = "If any question, please contact us";
    }
    else if (pointShop.SupplierId = 6543) {
    supplier = "Please call us";
    }
    else if (pointShop.SupplierId = 8723) {
    supplier = "You are welcome to write us";
    }
}
```

I am printing out the supplier like this:

```
<span>
   @supplier
</span>
```

There is 100% an id in my order there is 27942. But I am not getting the text printet out. Just an empty field. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that supposed to be ASP.NET/Razor templates?

Comment: `@supplier` is what you need

Comment: Make sure your if/elses are using the assignment `=` and not the comparison `==` too or you'll wonder what's going on there.  And you might need to do `string supplier = string.Empty`, currently you're comparing it and not declaring it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I run my code as it is in my question, I am getting this error: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type ''int'' to ''bool''` When I set the `==` in my if statement the code is compiling withour errors, but no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're miss using `=` and `==` as others have eluded too.

```
@{
    var pointShop = Model.Order.OrderLines[0];
    string supplier == null;

    if (pointShop.SupplierId = 27942) {
    supplier = "If any question, please contact us";
    }
    else if (pointShop.SupplierId = 6543) {
    supplier == "Please call us";
    }
    else if (pointShop.SupplierId = 8723) {
    supplier == "You are welcome to write us";
    }
}
```

let's take this line by line.

```
 string supplier == null;
```

this shouldn't compile so I'm not sure what you're actually running.  I think you're intending to create an empty string varible, the proper way to do that is this:

```
string supplier = String.Empty;
```

or `var supplier  = String.Empty;`

Then in your equality checks in your if statements you're doing assignment not evaluation.  = is assignment == is evaluation.

```
if (pointShop.SupplierId = 27942) {
    supplier = "If any question, please contact us";
    }
```

in the if statement pointShop.SupplierId will be assigned a value of 27942 instead of evaulating the SupplierId and checking it's value against 27942.  You need

```
if (pointShop.SupplierId == 27942) {
    supplier = "If any question, please contact us";
    }
```

instead.

All this can be checked in the debugger by putting break points in your razor view and stepping into it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you got a bunch of if all checking the same value, a switch...case might be the cleaner solution. The next step up from that would be a array or `Dictionary<int, string>`.

You have place where you use the comparision operator, rather then the assignment operator:

```
supplier == "Please call us";
```

This will always be false, as null does not equal any string. But it will be a false; wich kind of makes no sense for the compiler.